# Steel basement beam rusting

Tags: basement, moisture, beam, steel, rust

We supply steel beams in Western NY and we apply a structural steel primer to all beams. We have a customer who has beams that are rusting in a basement. The beams have been in place for 3-4 years, not exposed to the elements for more than probably a week after the initial delivery. This happened in another one of his builds as well and we went over and scraped the beams in the existing basement and re-primed them. The homeowner stated that he has been through 4 dehumidifiers in the past 4 years. We told him that it appears to be more of a moisture issue and not an issue with our steel primer, to which he agreed to. Re-priming the beams is just a band-aid to appease everyone but I do not think this is going to solve the problem long-term. Looking for an expert opinion as to wether this is an actual moisture problem stemming from poor waterproofing or something else.

[image]

Comment: Any chemicals/acids/chlorine/wet-cell batteries stored in that basement? Fumes can have a powerful impact on rusting of steel.

Comment: A hygrometer could confirm a moisture problem (I would call a high reading sufficient for confirmation but not necessary for confirmation). A wood moisture content meter would give you MC values that you could convert to relative humidity through an equilibrium moisture content table. Again, sufficient but not necessary.

Comment: That scale should be sandblasted off of there before repriming. An angle grinder with a wire wheel could do it, maybe, without involving a third party. I can only imagine the nasty air, though.

Comment: If nearly all of your steel is delivered during "building season" but this builder had you deliver in wintry conditions, the beam(s) could have picked up a coating of salt spray, calcium chloride or some other road salt. If not cleaned off with copious clean water before the beam was placed, that could account for *just these two beams* rusting badly.

Comment: Consider using zinc rich primer from now on or at least presenting the option to customers. At least check into the price differential. That stuff doesn't like alkyd paint top coats, though, so you might be signing up for 100 painting complaints instead of 2 corrosion complaints.

Answer (score 4):

This is a problem with two issues.

The location is high moisture content, as stated by the owner.

You have only primer on the steel beam. Left alone, in time primer will draw in moisture and cause rust faster.  The beam must be painted to provide a coating to seal the steel.

What type of paint would be best answered by a local painting expert with knowledge of your product and the location of the structure.

Comment: We send out thousands of steel beams with only steel primer and this issue has only presented itself these two times. I would say that at least 90% of our steel that goes in a new home never gets a finish coat of paint.

Comment: Doing something wrong but not having consequences, does not mean it was not done wrong.  Primer is NOT a finish coating.  I have experience with handling metals in an industrial manufacturing situation. Metals got a coating of oil to prevent oxidation, (rust).  Primer was done only shortly prior to painting.   You can refuse to believe me. However that does not change the properties of the physics of the situation.

Comment: You could serve yourself well by adding a disclaimer to any sale, that the unit must be painted and not left in bare primer to avoid oxidation. Then it is the end user's responsibility to do the painting.

Comment: I will never refuse to believe anyone, that is why I am asking the question. I was just wondering if there was a chance that it could be an issue with something else like the waterproofer that was used on this build. We find it hard to believe that it is only this one homebuilder that has had this issue or at least brought it to our attention.

Comment: As stated. This situation had the 2 elements that combined caused the problem.  High moisture in the air, ( humidity), that was not present in other locations.  The primer , that acted like a bit of a sponge, drawing in the moisture.  If there is no moisture in the air, or little,  the primer will not get overloaded and be able to allow the humidity to be dispersed before oxidation becomes evident.  However painting and creating a seal will prevent moisture from getting to the surface and oxidation will not take place.

Comment: You now know that in a high humidity situation the beam will oxidise. Any good contractor should know this.  However to protect yourself, ( company) a disclaimer advising of proper painting should be given with any sale.

Comment: Those are famous words in contract documents: "Zinc rich primer." Be cautious about top coating the stuff, though. It doesn't like alkyd paint. I was given a can of zinc paint to apply once. There was a 1" blob of immobile zinc at the bottom of the can. I'm always cautious about QC with zinc paints because of that one experience.

Answer (score 0):

Although similar to the other answer, I  would like to phrase it differently.

The beams are metal, hence cooler than the surroundings. They are also in a basement. Moisture **will** condense on them. The amount of rust on the bottom lip is further evidence of such condensation.

Here in NZ, they are painted, and they still rust. After 18 months  when we opened the side of our house for extension, I  was unhappy with the rust. I  had the original Engineer, Architect and Supplier certify to me that they were still okay. This was insurance purposes.

This case is really no different to having them outside. In which case, down under, they would galvanised by dipping. And then painted.

I think you should offer this as an option, even if to protect yourself.

Comment: Technically the metal feels cooler at temperature below human body temp because of its higher heat conductance (compared to, say, wood), not because it's cooler than ambient temperature. It sucks the heat out of you. If the ends are in contact with a cooler surface, though, then the heat conductance can make it colder than surroundings.